# Rails - Add custom item to select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this line of code:

```
<%= select "family", "num_of_children", (1..10), { :include_blank => true } %>
```

I would like to add one item at the end of the list. In this case: I want a "more" option as the last item.
How can I do that?

Comment: If you want to change the scope of your question and accept a different answer after you've already accepted the one that answered the original scope of your question – that's fine. But you should also consider changing your original post to reflect the answer that was ultimately accepted as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<%= select "family", "num_of_children", (1..10).to_a + [['more', '11']], { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Convert the range to an array, then append `'more'` to it:

```
<%= select "family", "num_of_children", (1..10).to_a << 'more', { :include_blank => true } %>
```

Comment: I like it, cleaner than my answer.

Comment: And if I want the last **value** to be 11. i.e. leave the "more" as the displayed option and have a custom value. How can I do that?

Comment: Sorry, I'm unclear as to what you mean. Can you please amend your post to include a detailed explanation of what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: @NoamB., if my answer correctly addresses your question as it stands, would you kindly consider accepting it as correct?

Comment: @LuísRamalho it gives me the option more11 with the vallue more11. I want the value to be "11" and the dispayed string to be "more"

Comment: Sorry @NoamB., I meant `(1..10).to_a << ['more', '11']` or `(1..10).to_a + [['more', '11']]`